# How to design multiple rows with unique one-to-many relations to the same table in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm using a headless cms called [directus](https://getdirectus.com/) for my website that uses MySQL for storing content. However I'm stuck on how to design multiple rows with unqiue one-to-many relations to the same table in the same table.

```
Page (Overview) -> One-to-Many -> Page Item -> One-to-Many -> Articles
     (Sponsors) -> One-to-Many -> Page Item -> One-to-Many -> Articles
```

Overview and Sponsors have their own unique ID which makes their articles unique, however when added to the Page table they will have the same Articles because of the ID provided by Page to link them together. I've only experience in NoSQL databases so my structure is probably not optimal.

Any solution to this?

Comment: I suggest normalized.  For details, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: It's a classic parent-child relation. You should add to the child record a pointer to the parent record (Foreign key).

Comment: The table `PageItem` needs columns `id_overview` and `id_sponsors`.